# Object.isExtensible() is true, but Object.defineProperty() throws. Why?

Tags: javascript

In Firefox and Safari I'm seeing a situation where `Object.isExtensible()` is true, I can add a new property with regular property assignment (ie, `o.x = y`), but `Object.defineProperty()` throws "TypeError: Object.defineProperty(...) is not extensible".

This is happening with typed arrays, maybe other types as well. I'm trying to use `isExtensible()` to make sure that I don't try to define a property on the object.

I can put the defineProperty in a try/catch, but I'd like to understand what's going on here. Any ideas?

Here's an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/justinfagnani/qvgnk/

And the code:

```
function addProperty(o, name, value) {
  if (Object.isExtensible(o)) {
    Object.defineProperty(o, name, {'value': value});
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(addProperty(new Date(), 'foo', 1));
console.log(addProperty(new ArrayBuffer(), 'foo', 1));
```

This should at least print true or false for each call. In Firefox it throws on the ArrayBuffer.

Comment: It helps if you create a small example which demonstrates the problem. Maybe with [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: worked in chrome for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note: typed arrays are now in the ES6/ES2015 specification, where `ArrayBuffer`s are actually extensible. This answer is provided for prior reference.

---

The [Typed Array specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/) does not explicitly say anything about this, though it uses [Web IDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#ecmascript-binding) to describe the objects created, which says the following:

> Unless otherwise specified, the [[Extensible]] internal property of objects defined in this section has the value **true**.

I'm not sure why they have put this in the specification, but some reasons why they might have chosen to make `[[Extensible]]` true even if it isn't extensible include:

- Wanting to allow extensions from specific functions/paths (prohibited when it is false)
- Leaving open the possibility of allowing extending a host object (prohibited to change from false to true)

According the [the ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1) (the "standard" version of JavaScript), whether a host object throws on setting a variable or not is implementation dependent ([§8.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2)):

> **Host objects may implement these internal methods in any manner unless specified otherwise**; for example, one possibility is that `[[Get]]` and `[[Put]]` for a particular host object indeed fetch and store property values but `[[HasProperty]]` always generates false. However, if any specified manipulation of a host object's internal properties is not supported by an implementation, that manipulation must throw a `TypeError` exception when attempted.

None of the invariants given by the specification apply in this instance, so this is technically legal.

---

Note to clarify: even if `[[Extensible]]` is true, the host object's internal functions do not have to allow an object to be extended.  The specification only mandates that a host object is not extended if `[[Extensible]]` is false ([reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2)):

> The `[[DefineOwnProperty]]` internal method of a host object must not permit the addition of a new property to a host object if the `[[Extensible]]` internal property of that host object has been observed by ECMAScript code to be false.

The descriptions given in the specification in Table 8/9 ([§8.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2)) are misleading themselves in that they only concern native ECMAScript objects, not host objects - this is specifically said in the paragraphs preceding Table 8, that host objects are not subject to implementing the properties as described in those tables.

Comment: Yet the host objects are required to implement the internal `[[Extensible]]` property, so it would seem that if FF decided to make `ArrayBuffer` objects non-extensible, then their `Object.isExtensible()` must have a bug.

Comment: @user2736012: yes, they are - the `[[Extensible]]` property is indeed true.  However, the host object implementation does not have to follow that at all, and may throw a `TypeError` even if it is true.  The specification only stipulates that it may not extend an object if `[[Extensible]]` is false.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm saying that `[[Extensible]]` should be `false` in Firefox, so OP's check using `if (Object.isExtensible(o))` should be preventing the error.

Comment: @user2736012: the `[[Extensible]]` property _can_ be true.  Because a host object has its own internal methods for defining properties (**not necessarily the methods provided by the specification**), a host object may throw an error (with its own message saying that "the host object is not extensible") regardless of whether `[[Extensible]]` is true or false.

Comment: What I'm saying is that by requiring host objects to implement `[[Extensible]]`, they are requiring those objects to follow the semantics defined for that property in the spec. Objects that do not allow own properties to be added should have the `[[Extensible]]` property for those object set to `false`. No?

Comment: @user2736012: and there are no semantics defined for host objects in the specification regarding extensibility.  Yes, it would be a lot easier theoretically.  However, it _is_ allowed.

Comment: Yes there are. In ES3 there were none, but in ES5 there are more responsibilities for host objects. The `[[Extensible]]` property is one. When a host object must comply with a part of the spec, it is specifically called out. In this case, it is the `[[Extensible]]` property and its implied semantics.

Comment: @user2736012: In the specification, it says (word for word) the following: "The descriptions in these tables indicate their behaviour for native ECMAScript objects, unless stated otherwise in this document for particular kinds of native ECMAScript objects. Host objects may support these internal properties with any implementation-dependent behaviour as long as it is consistent with the specific host object restrictions stated in this document."  Other host object restrictions prescribed by the specification only consider when `[[Extensible]]` is false.

Comment: Right, and the specific host object restriction is given in the first sentence below ***Table 8***. *"Every object (including host objects) must implement all of the internal properties listed in Table 8."*

Comment: @user2736012: "implement" simply refers to creating an `[[Extensible]]` property that follows the value type domain.  The behaviour of this property is still implementation dependent for host objects.

Comment: ...ah, here's [Bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=775185) that looks relevant. Reading the comments now...

Comment: No, the properties like `[[Extensible]]` mean more than their mere existence. They represent semantics. If a host object could implement it in whatever way it wanted, that would be basically the same as not implementing it at all, making the restriction moot.

Comment: @user2736012: it is required to implement the property to the behaviours specified for when it is `false` and its immutability when it is observable to being `false` - no behaviour is speicifed for when it it is `true`.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're seeing that distinction. But given that it specifically refers to `Table 8`, and that the property is given definition in that table *"If `true`, own properties may be added to the object."*, it would seem clear that it is required to at least abide by that much. The `true/false` behaviors are mutually exclusive. So both don't need to be defined.

Comment: @user2736012: details are _crucial_.  **The descriptions in these tables indicate their behaviour for native ECMAScript objects...  Host objects may support these internal properties with any implementation-dependent behaviour.**

Comment: **...as long as it is consistent with the specific host object restrictions stated in this document.** The restriction is placed on host objects to abide by the behaviors described in Table 8.

Comment: @user2736012: that paragraph refers specifically to Table 8/9's description being only for native ECMAScript objects.

Comment: @user2736012: okay, thanks.  I'll edit my answer to clarify specifically your point being made.

Comment: Still seems messed up that they would return `true` when properties can't be added. I can't imagine what would compel this implementation decision.

Comment: @user2736012: most likely it is so that they don't have to abide by restrictions placed when `[[Extensible]]` is false... ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the discussion. I think this is kind of ridiculous behavior, but I see how it technically meets the spec. I guess I'll use a try/catch.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this behavior is dependent on strict mode and the JavaScript engine.

In V8 (Chrome), if strict mode is off, `o.x = y` will succeed, but not assign anything to `o.x`, while `Object.defineProperty` will *always* throw an exception, regardless of strict mode.

In strict mode `o.x` will throw an exception.

In Rhino `Object.defineProperty` will throw an exception and `o.x = y` will silently fail.

Here are some examples:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat6/6.0.37 >rhino -strict
Rhino 1.7 release 4 2012 06 18
js> var o = {a: 132};
js> Object.freeze(o);
[object Object]
js> Object.isExtensible(o);
false
js> o.x = 789;
789
js> o.x;
js> Object.defineProperty(o,'name',{value: 789})
js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: Cannot add properties to this object because extensible is false.
```

In V8

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat6/6.0.37 >node
> var o = {a: 123}
undefined
> Object.freeze(o)
{ a: 123 }   
> Object.isExtensible(o)
false
> o.x = 13
13
> o.x
undefined
> Object.defineProperty(o,'name',{value:123})
TypeError: Cannot define property:name, object is not extensible.
    at Function.defineProperty (native)
    at repl:1:9
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
```

In strict mode

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat6/6.0.37 >node --use_strict
> var o = {a: 123};
undefined
> Object.freeze(o);
{ a: 123 }
> Object.isExtensible(o);
false
> o.x = 13
TypeError: Can't add property x, object is not extensible
    at repl:1:6
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
```

Comment: Tried the above fiddle with `use strict` and it does not throw for me (Windows 8 Firefox 24.0 )

Comment: @AnthonySottile looks to be browser dependent, added some examples.